# Is there any way to get data in json format from google traffic api?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am trying to get data in json format. I tried lot by searching but no result is found. How should I get data in json format from google traffic api.

Comment: Use postman or hurl it to check and debug your url request. It will help you to manage JSON format.

Comment: we cannot make request of google traffic api v3 in postman

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and add a link to the api you are referring to and any code you are currently using to access it.    We need to see what you are doing in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean [Google traffic API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic) which is part of Google maps. 
The anwser is you cant it does not return data as json it returns data it as a data [layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) to be placed on top of google maps.

Comment: Hi Dalm thank you for your response .there is any way to get data in json format.
i want to get traffic color on particular  latitude and longitude.
like there is green indicate low traffic red indicate heavy traffic and want to save in database